# Problem with responsive Bootstrap Material: Too much space left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, responsive

So I have problems with this page:

I'm using [bootstrap-material-design](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)

The problem is when I go mobile view there is too much space on one side, right side all the height of the page like in screenshot:

#### Desktop

[image: Desktop view]

#### Mobile

[image: MOBILE]

So I checked everything with `max-width: 100%` but I can't find why this happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show us your code so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you give inline style  `width: 500px` in your form with class `form-inline`

Remove this and add it to class `form-inline`

```
.form-inline {
width: 500px
}
```

After this create a [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for small devices as below:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
 .form-inline {
  width: 100%
}
 }
```

I hope that help you.